# Error al crear programa con clase person y constructor de clase para obtener un mensaje de bienvenida personalizado

Tags: c#, clase, constructor

El error dice que hay un problema con el formato del string y la línea del error está señalada con un comentario.

Un funcionamiento adecuado del programa podría ser el siguiente:

Insert person name: `Babar`

Insert person age: `150`

Hello Babar you are 150 years old!

Press any key.

```
    using System;
    
    namespace Person
    {
class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;
        public Person(string name, int age) //constructor de clase que hace referencia a clase Person y sirve para poner un valor por defecto que no sea Null
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
    }
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int Age;
                string Name;
                Console.WriteLine("Insert person name:");
                Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert person age:");
                Age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Person p = new Person(Name, Age);
                Person constructperson = new Person("javier", 16); //constructor de clase
                Console.WriteLine("Hello {0] you are {1} years old!", p.Name, p.Age); //hay fallo en esta línea
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un error en el argumento `0` tiene un corchete en lugar de una llave:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0] you are {1} years old!", p.Name, p.Age);
```

Debería ser así:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello {0} you are {1} years old!", p.Name, p.Age);
```

Comment: Tiene que ser así para luego sustituirlo más adelante por la variable deseada ¿No es así?

Comment: Sí, mi error. Había puesto el código corregido.

Answer (score 1):

Debes cambiar el **`]`** por un **`}`** en donde deseas colocar la variable **`{0}`**.